# CD74HCT03E NAND Gate dont work

Tags: breadboard, nand

First of all I am new to this whole circuit building thing so please don't be too harsh on me.

I recently tried to build my first adder with NAND gates. So I went to a shop and bought some CD74HCT03E devices. To get started I just tried out the NAND gate but it didn't work.

I had a really really basic setup: a NAND gate, the power supply, and a LED. I already verified this circuit with my physics teacher and he sad that everything is fine. I also checked every pin with my voltmeter. Every input (A/B grounded) were at 0V and the output (Y) flicker but were also at 0V.

Here is an image of my circuit: [image]

Comment: We can help you better if you include the **schematic** of what you're buidling. Scan a drawing or better: use the schematic drawing tool (Edit your question, press the schematic icon).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

74HCT03 is open drain output. That means it can only pull the output low.

Try it this way..

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2feayhf.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thank you really much, that schematic really helped me :)

Answer (score 3):

The banner line title of the CD74HCT03E is

> High-Speed CMOS Logic
>
> Quad 2-Input NAND Gate with Open Drain

You got really unlucky on your first purchase, the NAND gate you purchased only drives low, it never drives high. It is an open-drain output.

You will need to add a pull-up resistor on 1Y to VCC.

You can also connect the LED directly to 1Y and move your ballast resistor as the pull-up to Vcc.

Comment: Thank you really much for you answer, it is working now :)

Comment: @Nimmi The part which you probably meant to buy is the 74(HCT)00, which has a "normal" (push-pull) output.

Answer (score 1):

Try this circuit.  It's how it should be connected.

Two 1's light LED.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpHuI9m.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Open Drain (collector) have their applications, but it may be best to stay away from them when experimenting.  Each output will require a "pull-up" to work.

One application is paralleling gates to a "wired OR" (or "wired AND") in this case.  Otherwise a third gate is required.

In the following circuit, activate either NAND to turn on LED.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2gMwxm.png)</sup>

Comment: YUp this will work too.. though inverted

Comment: @Trevor  But that is how it is meant to be used.  8)

Comment: I'd say so..yes ;)